# computing covariance to find variance

Tags: probability

An unbalanced coin, for which the probability to toss a head is 0.3, is tossed 10 times. Find the mean E(Y −2X) and variance Var(Y −2X), where X is the number of heads and Y is the number of tails in these 10 tosses.

I know how to find E(Y-2X). I know both X and Y are binomial distributions so their mean is np. Thus,

E(Y-2X)= E(Y)-2E(X)=7-6=1

However, when I compute variance, I am having some troubles.

Var(Y-2X)= Var(Y)+4Var(X)-2cov(X,Y). I know X, Y are not independent, but I'm not sure how to compute Cov(X,Y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you toss the coin $N$ times, then

$$
X + Y = N ~~~\Leftrightarrow~~~~ \color{blue}{Y} = N - X
$$

So $\color{blue}{Y} - 2X = \color{blue}{(N- X)} - 2X = N-3X$. Your problem is then reduced to finding

$$
\mathbb{E}[N - 3X] = N - 3\mathbb{E}[X]
$$

and

$$
\mathbb{V}{\rm ar}[N - 3X] = 9\mathbb{V}{\rm ar}[X]
$$

Answer (score 0):

A closed form for $Cov(X,Y)$ is $Cov(X,Y) = E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$.
X,Y follow binomial distributions so you re capable of finding everything except $E(XY)$ but you can notice that $Y = 10 - X$ and replace it inside.

Comment: Yes, but how can I find E(X^2)

Comment: $Var(X) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2 $ You know how to calculate the first and the third term so you can easily calculate the second